# NPN transistors level shifter

Tags: voltage-level, arduino-pro-mini, esp32

I'm going to use this for Arduino Pro Mini (5v version) to communicate with ESP32 via UART so I need level shifting. I found this circuit which uses NPN transistor and I'm also going to use it. This is the circuit I'm going to use...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMECV9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Are the resistors' value appropriate or do I have to change the collector resistor?

Comment: You don't have a collector resistor, you have a pullup resistor.

Comment: Can a moderator migrate this to the Electronical Engineering stackexchange please? This is purely about level shifting with transistors.

Comment: Are you aware that you can just use a voltage divider? Two resistors.

Comment: Those values look fine to me.